# PHP only display last id number in last row

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to display 6 items in one page with 3 items in each row. And when the user clicks on the image link it will redirect to another page and display the id. However when the user clicks on the image it does redirect to another page but it shows the id of the last product in the last row of the page, and this is not correct.  I'm not sure where I made the mistake. I hope you can look at my code and give me a hint where the mistake lies.

```
      <?PHP
session_start();

function connect()
{
    $servername = xxxxxxxx;
    $username   = xxxxxxxx;
    $password   = xxxxxxxx;
    $dbname     = xxxxxxxx;

    $conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
    if (!$conn) {
        echo 'connection is invalid';
    } else {
        mysqli_select_db($conn, "mytest");

    }

    return $conn;
}

function getData()
{
    $conn = connect();

    if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
        $startrow = 0;
    } else {
        $startrow = (int) $_GET['startrow'];

    }

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_products LIMIT $startrow, 6";
    $getdata = mysqli_query($conn, $sql) or die(mysqli_error());


    $cell_img = mysqli_num_rows($getdata);

    $i       = 0;
    $per_row = 3;
    echo "<table id='productTumb'><tr id='proRow'>";
    $data = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata)) {
        //echo "<a href='ProDet.html'></a>";
        echo "<td><a href='test.php'><img style='vertical-align: bottom;' width='218px' height='332px' src='" . $row['products_image'] . "'/ ></a></td>";
        $data .= "<td style='background-color:#FF0004'>" . $row['product_name'] . "</td>";
        $product_id = $row['products_id'];

        $_SESSION['id'] = $product_id;
        if (++$i % $per_row == 0 && $i > 0 && $i <= $cell_img) {
            echo "</tr><tr>$data</tr><tr>";
            $data = '';




        }
    }

    for ($x = 0; $x < $per_row - $i % $per_row; $x++) {


        echo "<td></td>";


    }

    echo "</tr>";
    echo "</table>";


    echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?startrow=' . ($startrow + 5) . '">Next >>></a>';
    $prev = $startrow - 5;
    if ($prev >= 0)
        echo '<a href="' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . '?startrow=' . $prev . '"> <<<< Previous</a>';



}







?>
```

Comment: Please format your code to be more readable.

Comment: @Justinas sorry for the messy code

Comment: how you are getting product id in test.php page? using $_SESSION['id'] ?

Comment: @RavinderReddyyeah I used $pid = $_SESSION['id'];
  echo $pid;

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line of code  $_SESSION['id'] = $product_id; will set last product id to SESSION.(overwrites previous ids)

Try to add product id to the anchor href tag

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getdata)) {
  echo "<td><a href='test.php?id=".$row['products_id']."'><img style='vertical-align: bottom;' width='218px' height='332px' src='" . $row['products_image'] . "'/ ></a></td>";
  ......
  }
```

In test.php file get id by below code

```
 if(isset($_GET)){
  $pid = $_GET['id']; 
  echo $pid;
 }
```

hope this will helps you.

Comment: I was writing same answer :)

Comment: @Peter thinking same :)